# Ideas to migrate from Symfony forms to Client side generated forms populated through AJAX requests

Tags: reactjs, forms, symfony, fosrestbundle

I've been working on a Symfony 3 project for a while and now have lots of quite complicated forms (mostly a filter bar changing from page to page depending on page type, input, and other factors). These forms are quite complicated, have lots of interrelated dropdowns, etc.

Because the project is quite old and I'd like to transition to SPA, I'm looking for the least painful way to get rid of Symfony forms and instead use AJAX requests to populate the data and so on... So basically React and REST API vs monolith.

Can you give me some suggestions on how would you approach this, or maybe you've been working on something similar? I have a gut feeling that I'd need to get rid of Symfony forms and start from scratch writing client-side HTML/js and API to populate the form.

Any advice appreciated, 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check API Platform?

Comment: I'm doing something similar now, at least I think it's similar.  I started with CodeIgniter and its forms, but didn't want to use Symfony2.8's Twig or Forms, so I wrote my own server-side mechanism that basically stuffed html/javascript/jquery text into an array that is then joined together in a long string and sent to the client browser.  Since the browser just sees regular pages, it can use Ajax to send and request data to/from the server, which works much like the original page request.  This allowed me focus on learning core Symfony and quickly convert my CodeIgniter to Symfony.